# Send message from input field into database by pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html

i've done a web chat which the codes are:

```
<div id="namebox">Name: <input type="text"  id="name" autofocus autocomplete="on" ></div>  
<div id="msgbox" >Message: <input type="text" id="message"></div>
<div id="submitbox"><button onClick="postMessageToDB(); return false;" id="submit">Submit</button></div>
```

So, the message goes into the database fine by clicking the button submit, however i was wondering to ad a code to jut press enter and it will be sent, so there will be 2 options.

I am using **onClick** and **onKeypress** which it is not working.

```
<div id="submitbox"><button onClick="postMessageToDB(); return false;" id="submit" onkeypress="postMessageToDB(this, event); return false;">Submit</button></div>
```

Where the javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function postMessageToDB(inputElement, event) {  
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {   
            inputElement.div.submit();  
        }  
    }  
</script>
```

Im not using **form** because it was asked to be **div**, not **form**.

Really appreciate for any help.
Thank you very much

Comment: How is it getting to the database?

Comment: by click submit button

Answer (score 0):

Your code provided will only work when `postMessageToDB()` is called... it's not listening for a keypress.

***Using jQuery:***

```
$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if( e.keyCode==13 ) {
        postMessageToDB([...]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it keeps my div chatlog loading loading without display the content previously inserted into database =/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function, you can do this by adding an EventListener to document and then check if it's enter that was pressed.

```
      var keyevent = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "keypress" : "keydown";  // fit browser 

      document.addEventListener(keyevent, function(e) {
          if  (event.keyCode == 13) {
              var a = document.getElementById('name').value; //get field values
              var b = document.getElementById('message').value; //get field values
              postMessageToDB(inputElement, event); // as I said, not sure what this will do, but you need to get the data you want to pass first within this function.
              }
       });
```

Then, just remove the keypress checkup from you function and you should check this line, I can't see that this is going to work:

```
inputElement.div.submit();
```

Comment: it allow me to display the message previously inserted into data base but not working by pressing enter.

Comment: Yeah, because this is not submitted with pressing enter. which fields do you want to submit exactly? @Hugo

Comment: needed submit `div name` and `div message` which will be displayed like this: **[ Hugo ] 06:07pm -­ test on click submit**

Comment: so you need an ajax call or what?

Comment: i dont think so! Java should be fine! I have done this before, but i dont know whats i am doing wrong! The whole web chat is working fine, but when i add this feature, does not work, i mean, the whole thing keeps running, less the press key